# Can I turn an in-use external drive into a live boot disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, live-usb

I need to really quick set up a live-boot disk for Ubuntu to recover information from my other computer (Windows won't stop crashing) and I have a 2TB external drive that has a *lot* of empty space sitting on it. My question is thus:

Must I transfer all the files currently on the drive off temporarily and then load and partition, or can I somehow partition my USB HDD for a live-boot environment without losing/transferring all its stored data?

Thank you!

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. But, preferably, make a backup of your data. You can also use `gParted` to partition your external drive. Then, use `UnetBooting`, or the Startup disk creator included in Ubuntu to create the live media.

Warning!. Do not create a new partition table, or you will lose all your data.

Answer (score 0):

Boot live environment from usb-thumbdrive, then connect usb-hdd disk. Copy/paste from crashing Windows disk to a new folder you would create on usb-external disk. Ubuntu can mount and access NTFS (Windows) partitions.

You will only have formatted a thumbdrive. Don't format the external hard disk.

You may use but not limited to, Rufus, YUMI Installer or Universal USB Installer from another working Windows machine to make bootable usb thumbdrive.